# Reading matrices into Mata

Tags: matrix, stata

I have some large matrices I want to process in Mata, i.e., typical matrix operations such as inverting, multiplying, etc.  These are Stata files with variable names in the first row.  Some are quite large, >15 GB.  So, the first problem is reading the data.  I read something about setting up views, but my version of Stata does not show any help for st_view.  The help for Mata talks about opening a file with fopen(), but it's pretty cryptic.  I also read something about Mata adding changes to the original data.  I'd prefer some strategy that doesn't alter my original data as it takes a long time to create the original matrices.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Some misinformation here!

1. If your matrix is already read in, `fopen()` sounds irrelevant to you.
2. If your matrix consists of variables already in Stata, consider using `putmata`. However, if variable names really are in the first row (i.e. observation) you may need to take them out and `destring`.
3. `st_view()` is documented; presumably you are just looking in the wrong place. Start at `help m4_stata`.
4. Mata won't change your Stata data unless you ask it to.